# Eclipse - sharing workspace through dropbox (.project files error because of wrong path)

Tags: eclipse, workspace, project-settings

I'm sharing my eclipse workspace with my dropbox.

I have my dropbox folder at `M:\Dropbox` at home and at `D:\Dropbox` at work.

At home, I want to keep M: for "My files"-Drive and don't want to change that to D: and at work, M: is already mapped...

Is there another way than making symbolic links to a location I can use on both machines? My goal is, that I don't have to change anything on my home computer...

Another problem is, that I'm using a variable and relativ paths to this variable for importing libraries. So I just have to change the single variable, if the path changes.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just remap M: to something else at work and then map D: to M:

Edit:
otherwise check out this link 
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270978/

for consistency i'll copy the important part:

> As I say, you can't share workspaces, but you might get away with
>   sharing the same project. Here's how.
>
> 1. Create the project on one computer, get it more or less how you'd
>      like it (i.e.: simple Java Project, Dynamic Web Project, etc. as created
>      by Eclipse). You'll be able to add or delete source code later, but the
>      project should exist enough for Eclipse to recognize it.
> 2. Copy the important parts of the project to your dropbox location.
> 3. From inside Eclipse, discard the original project including source
>      files (it prompts you to be cautious about this).
> 4. Create a new project in the same (or a different) workspace. When the
>      wizard comes up, you can name it what you want, but tell it to get the
>      source files from another location and not to copy them into the
>      workspace. Eclipse will consume the project from dropbox, I think.
> 5. Repeat this from your other computer from its Eclipse using,
>      obviously, its own workspace.
> 6. The changes you make from one computer will be reflected in the
>      other. You will have to right-click your project and choose Refresh when
>      you change computers.
> 7. All third-party libraries (JARs) must be copied to a path inside your
>      project. Otherwise, your .classpath file will acquire full filesystem
>      pathnames which will not hold true on both computers. Another way of
>      causing this problem is to associate Javadoc or source code with any of
>      those third-party JARs (let's say you wanted Javadoc for hibernate3.jar,
>      you're screwed as soon as you do that).
>
> I have not done this; there may be a hole in what I'm telling you or,
>   you may accidentally do something that destroys your ability to do it
>   this way (as suggested by #7).
>
> As I pointed out in my original reply, it's better to use a
>   version-control system for this (and, obviously, there are other
>   benefits too).

i think this will cover the main idea of the forum post.
I myself took the solution of using a version-control system since it is a cleaner way of doing things

Comment: that would be the solution, I know, but the mapping to M: is done automatically... M: maps to the user directory on EVERY computer in my company and therefore I don't want to change that...

Comment: but in the end, if there is absolutely no other solution, I will have to do it that way anyways... unmapping M: on startup and remapping everything the way I want it...

Comment: Check out the link i posted with the edit, i think this sums up the idea of sharing a project with oneself in eclispe

Comment: Another option of course would be to not use dropbox but instead use a VPN if possible and map the drive from work on your computer at home but i don't count that as a valid solution since it still produces mapping problems and the question states that this should be done through dropbox

Comment: actually I already use a local SVN in my dropbox... I though don't always want to check in and out... I will try your solution, it sounds good to me... Two workspaces means I can even define different variables and can use this with extern libs so I think I don't have to copy extern libs to project folder

Comment: actually, that in combination with a local library var (so I don't have to copy foreign libs to workspace) is the PERFECT solution, I just share my home workspace through my dropbox and at work, I use my own workspace there and just import the projects without copying the source... That's all that have to be done and now I won't have sync problems anymore because of the different .project files or because my home computer is running with eclipse open while being at work. Thx a lot, you really helped me